# XML Schema with a combination of choice and all

Tags: xsd

I want to do the validations like:

```
<A>
   <B> or <C>
   <D>
</A>
```

In the , the first element should be one of the B and C. The second element is D. And at the same time, the first element B or C and the second element do not in sequence. It could become  and . Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Can you please add valid xml for 2nd part of your description, because I do not follow it -> "And at the same time, the first element B or C and the second element do not in sequence. It could become and . "

Comment: the following works:<B> <D>, <D> <B>, <C> <D>, <D> <C>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the best practice. It should be as below:

```
<xs:element name="A">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="Choice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:all>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string"/>

 <xs:element name="Choice" abstract="true"/> 

 <xs:element name="B" substitutionGroup="Choice"> 
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="C" substitutionGroup="Choice"> 
 </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

To match your example, please try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="A">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You have to use two things here, the first one is `<xs:choice>` which allows only one elements to be present in xml.

In order to make an element optional (D) you have to specify `minOccurs="0"`.

**Edited (after feedback):** All valid cases are covered with this XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:complexType name="OurType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="D"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element ref="B"/>
          <xs:element ref="C"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element ref="B"/>
          <xs:element ref="C"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="D"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="A" type="OurType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: In you answer, it is in sequence. I don't want the two elements in sequence. The valid cases are listed. :)

Comment: @ChengChen edited answer to cover all valid cases mantioned by you.

Comment: I got the best practise and just posted it. Thanks for your answering though.